# PHP CMS for admin'ing content

Tags: php, cms

I'm looking for a CMS with the following features and the flexibility to upgrade easily. I'm only interested in the admin side of it; I'm not looking to admin a website. The end-goal is to have a site that allows me to administer content.

- the ability to define an object and automatically have the database table created, along with crud pages (and forms) automatically created
- inbuilt first-class objects like images and basic image handling such as rotate and crop (by dragging a square around where I want to crop)
- object relations automatically handled from specifying them
- some kind of import / export to allow me to add new records or export data to CSV
- the ability to define custom operations on data - e.g. the price is £4.50, and I want to be able to remove / add VAT, or to display the amount of sales of a product by counting the amount of sales for that product that's stored in the sales table etc.

Please not Drupal. I find it tedious and painfully slow.

Comment: "I'm only interested in the admin side of it" : So, no publicly visible pages? Only you can see the website?

Comment: "Admin side" referring to the CRUD aspects. There doesn't need to be any security as the only purpose is to admin content, not facilitate presention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally found a reasonable solution: [**Microsoft Access**](https://products.office.com/access)! Yes, really!

As it's a single user, I'm not fussed that it's not accessible via a browser, also, it has VBA (which is Visual Basic Actionscript) and with a bit of fuss, allows me to use C# Dll's or .Net functionality, has built-in forms and quite a few other niceities!

Answer (score 1):

The closest that I can think of as per your requirement is not a CMS but more of a framework so I'm looking into Yii and a couple of extension

For db CRUD functions, you can use gii crud generator, just create your db structure and the code will be generated to froms from basic crud operations-
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/710/crud-operation-in-yii-framework/

For image editing - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image-editor/

For DB exporting - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-dump-db/

For DB importing - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dlhelperdatabase/

For the ability to customize data, I think you need to create your custom functions to achieve your desired output for that

If your into a highly customizable PHP CMS, what I'm thinking is Wordpress coz it has a built in image editing functions, woocommerce and has a lot of price customization, but I'm doubting that it will be fast for your requirement

Comment: Isn't Yii 1.1 being deprecated in place of 2.0?

Comment: yes, but most of your required functions is readily available in yii1 and not yet readily available in yii2, you might need to do more coding to it

Comment: The db importer / exporter only works with sql, not csv format